# Should I use my cold weather boots in 40-80°F weather?

Tags: boots, footwear

I need to select a pair of shoes for when I go out to Yosemite this weekend.  The weather has been fluctuating like crazy - last we checked, there was a foot of snow on the ground, but now the lowlands are completely melted.  I had originally planned on bringing my pair of [cold weather boots](http://www.columbia.com/Men%E2%80%99s-Bugaboot%C2%AE-Plus-XTM/BM1498,default,pd.html#), but it's looking like the weather might be in the range of 40-80F (4.4-26.7C) now.  I have a pair of [trail shoes](http://www.ahnu.com/mens-woodacre-lightweight-rugged-trail-shoes/AF1180,default,pd.html?dwvar_AF1180_color=BRCT&start=10&cgid=men-view-all) I could bring, but I'm not certain if they're up to doing 20+ miles in 3 days.  I could buy a new pair of hiking boots, but that's shelling out a little bit more money now.

Has anyone taken a pair of cold weather boots out in the spring before?  Did you have any issues with them being too warm?  Would you do it again, or would you rather use a separate pair of hiking boots?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cold weather boot will definitely be too warm for 40-80F (4.4-26.7C).

I will definitely choose warmer hiking boots rather and bring  two pairs socks types in such condition : warm and normal. Just start with the normal socks and if you are too cold then switch for the warmer.

Remember that sweating is worse than being a bit cold.

Last but not least, listen to your body :)

Comment: I ended up taking both. The shoes were great for the warm dry part, the boots were great in the snow.  It was definitely convenient to be able to switch when drying out.  Reasonable solution when you don't have money for proper warm weather boots.

Comment: great :-) hope you had a great week end